# html2canvas - IndexSizeError

Tags: javascript

I am trying to take an image that is loaded into a div on my page and try and either pass in the raw data fro the image, or try and copy the image to a location.

The best method i could find was using html2canvas

I am getting the following error when trying to open my image into a window to preview:

JavaScript runtime error: IndexSizeError

I have read a few posts advising that i could render the div using the following method:

```
html2canvas($("#mapDiv"), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
                var imgData = canvas.GetContext("2d").getImageData(bounds.left, bounds.top, bounds.width, bounds.height);
                var myImage = imgData.toDataURL("image/png");
                window.open(myImage);
            }
        });
```

The problem is occuring on the following line in the html2canvas js file

```
ctx.drawImage(canvas, bounds.left, bounds.top, bounds.width, bounds.height, 0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height);
```

Is it possible to render an image that is dynamically loaded into a div in this way, as i cant pass in the pixel parameters due to users having different resolutions

and if it is possible, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand what your end goal is. Are you trying to render an image into a <canvas>?

Comment: i'm going to try and convert the image into raw data to pass it to a database, but i actually need to render the image first

Comment: Why are you using html2canvas and not just just the context.drawImage() method?

Answer (score 0):

```
function capture(id) {

        html2canvas([document.getElementById(id)], {
            logging: true,
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
                //console.log(dataUrl)
                $('#img-out').attr("src", canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));

                $.post("/upload-img", {img: dataUrl, name: id}, function (res) {
                    console.log(res) 


                    location.href = $("#" + id).attr("shareUrl") + "&picture=" + (window.location.protocol + "//" +window.location.host + "/" + res.filePath)

                } )
            }
        });
    }
```

pass id of element you want snapshot.